# Create unconnected SSLSocket over an existing Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am implementing a custom TLS socket factory over a SOCKS proxy. Among other methods I **should** override is `Socket createSocket()` which just creates an unconnected Socket which will be connected somewhere later in the code.

So in the TLS socket factory **without** a SOCKS proxy, the way I implement it is the following:

```java
@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
  // Initialize my SSL Context
  SSLContext sslCtx = initializeSSLContext();
  SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
  // Return an unconnected socket
  return socketFactory.createSocket();
}
```

In my TLS socket factory **over** SOCKS the equivalent is roughly like this:

```java
@Override
  public Socket createSocket() throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    // proxy is an instance of java.net.Proxy
    Socket socks = new Socket(proxy);

    // Initialize my SSL context
    SSLContext sslCtx = initializeSSLContext();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
    return socketFactory.createSocket(socks, ????, ????, true);
  }
```

As I mentioned earlier I need to be able to create a socket without connecting it. `SSLSocketFactory` provides two methods to create sockets over an existing one but both assume that you know the `host:port` you are connecting to.

Is there any way to create a TLS socket over an existing socket (proxy) but without providing the target host?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sup! Do you find out a solution? I have the same need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket()` to create an unconnected socket. Check the docs here for more details [SSLSocketFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html)

Comment: Sure. That's what I'm doing on the non-SOCKS factory (first snippet), but then how do you set the Proxy socket?